# C++ Compound literal

Tags: c++, c, inline, compound-assignment

In C i can do this:

```
ppackage ppnull() {
    return (ppackage) {
        .type = NULL
    }
}
```

However, in C++ I get syntax errors. I use the GNU `g++` compiler. Is there a switch to enable this?

Comment: This is not standard C++, do `ppackage p = { }; return p;` or just `return { };` if you have C++11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `c++11` you can use initializer list:

```
struct ppackage
{
    void* type;
};

ppackage ppnull()
{
    return {nullptr};
}
```

Or just

```
ppackage ppnull()
{
    return {};
}
```

Comment: Putting `nullptr` in there is unnecessary

Comment: Now ppackage has an anonymouse union with many structs inside it. There i must have `{.type='f', .fetch={"home"}}`

Comment: @imacake, well, this doesn't work with unions, you have to change syntax or reconsider your design (use constructors, but it makes your `struct` incompatible with `C`). You should tell, what you can do, than I can provide more complete solution.