# C++ version of C99 temporary local array variable

Tags: c++, c99

Regardless of any potential pitfalls of it's use, I found this code snippet in one of the ffmpeg header files:

```
/**
 * Convenience macro, the return value should be used only directly in
 * function arguments but never stand-alone.
 */
#define av_err2str(errnum) \
    av_make_error_string((char[AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE]){0}, AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE, errnum)
```

My question is about **`(char[AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE]){0}`**.
It essentially creates a `char[]` array on the stack and passes its stack address as a `char*` to be filled in-place by `av_make_error_string()`.

This is C99 syntax.

Does pre-C++11 have an equivalent syntax?
Will this also work with C++11?

Comment: Use the various C++ settings on ideone.com and try it for yourself? http://ideone.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Compound literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436480/c-compound-literal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but in C++ the lifetime of the array is *actually* something temporarily (only is alive for the duration of its surrounding expression statement, roughly speaking). In your C99 example, the lifetime of the array will be its surrounding block, actually.

```
template<int I>
struct Array {
  Array() {}
  char data[I];
};
```

Then you can say

```
av_make_error_string(
    (Array<AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE>().data, 
     AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE, 
     errnum)
```

The sole purpose of the user-defined constructor is to prevent the zero-initialization of `data` when you do the the `Array<>()`. If you want to have it initialized, remove the constructor. Of course, boost::array just works aswell

```
av_make_error_string(
    (boost::array<char, AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE>().c_array(), 
     AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE, 
     errnum)
```

Comment: Good answer. 
I wonder if there is no pure-language syntax way to do it (as in C99), i.e. no need for extra classes.